# Access Information from an associated model in an iterator block

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On a user profile page, I want to show the "reviews" that that user has as well as "review requests".  I currently have it set up where listing review requests works, like this:

```
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @review_requests = @user.review_requests.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end
```

and the view:

```
    <ol class="review_request">
      <%= render 'user_review_requests' %>
    </ol>
```

with partial:

```
  <% @review_requests.each do |review_request| %>
  <li>
    <span class="description">
      <%= review_request.description %>
    </span>
   blah blah blah....(there's more of much the same)

@reviews = @user.reviews.paginate(page: params[:page])
```

I also want to show reviews, but the thing is, a lot of the information about the review I want to show is actually stored in the ReviewRequest model.  So doing this wouldn't work:

add to the show controller:

```
@reviews = @user.reviews.paginate(page: params[:page])
```

and the iterator block:

```
<% @reviews.each do |review| %>
  <li>
    <span class="description">
      <%= review.review_request_id.description %>
    </span>
```

How can I access information from the ReviewRequest model that is associated with each connected review so I can show it on the profile page.

BTW - review requests have_many reviews and reviews belong_to review requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When accessing a `belongs_to` association, you access it via the association name (`review_request`), not the column name (`review_request_id`). Something like this:

```
<span class="description">
  <%= review.review_request.description %>
</span>
```